# How to (dynamically) join array with a struct, to get a value from the struct for each element in the array?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse/flatten a JSON data, containing an array and a struct.
For every "Id" in "data_array" column, I need to get the "EstValue" from "data_struct" column. Column name in "data_struct" is the actual id (from "data_array"). Tried my best to use a dynamic join, but getting error "Column is not iterable". Can't we use dynamic join conditions in PySpark, like we can in SQL? Is there any better way for achieving this?

JSON Input file:

```json
{
  "data_array": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "DEF"
    }
  ],
  "data_struct": {
    "1": {
      "estimated": {
        "value": 123
      },
      "completed": {
        "value": 1234
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "estimated": {
        "value": 456
      },
      "completed": {
        "value": 4567
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
Id  Name EstValue CompValue
1   ABC  123      1234
2   DEF  456      4567
```

My PySpark code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
rawDF = spark.read.json([f"abfss://{pADLSContainer}@{pADLSGen2}.dfs.core.windows.net/{pADLSDirectory}/InputFile.json"], multiLine = "true")

idDF = rawDF.select(explode("data_array").alias("data_array")) \
    .select(col("data_array.id").alias("id")) 

idDF.show(n=2,vertical=True,truncate=150)


finalDF = idDF.join(rawDF, (idDF.id == rawDF.select(col("data_struct." + idDF.Id))) )

finalDF.show(n=2,vertical=True,truncate=150)
```

Error:

> def __iter__(self): raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self joins create problems. In this case, you can avoid the join.

You could make arrays from both columns, zip them together and use `inline` to extract into columns. The most difficult part is creating array from "data_struct" column. Maybe there's a better way, but I only could think of first transforming it into *map* type.

Input:

```py
s = """
{
  "data_array": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "DEF"
    }
  ],
  "data_struct": {
    "1": {
      "estimated": {
        "value": 123
      },
      "completed": {
        "value": 1234
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "estimated": {
        "value": 456
      },
      "completed": {
        "value": 4567
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
rawDF = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([s]), multiLine = "true")
```

Script:

```py
id = F.transform('data_array', lambda x: x.id).alias('Id')
name = F.transform('data_array', lambda x: x['name']).alias('Name')
map = F.from_json(F.to_json("data_struct"), 'map<string, struct<estimated:struct<value:long>,completed:struct<value:long>>>')
est_val = F.transform(id, lambda x: map[x].estimated.value).alias('EstValue')
comp_val = F.transform(id, lambda x: map[x].completed.value).alias('CompValue')
df = rawDF.withColumn('y', F.arrays_zip(id, name, est_val, comp_val))
df = df.selectExpr("inline(y)")

df.show()
# +---+----+--------+---------+
# | Id|Name|EstValue|CompValue|
# +---+----+--------+---------+
# |  1| ABC|     123|     1234|
# |  2| DEF|     456|     4567|
# +---+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine, saved my day, thank you!!
Thanks for sharing your knowledge/expertise and helping me out here.